# shell unnanme -r command not found

Tags: command-line, files, make, c, makefile

```
shantanu@LAPTOP-3NM82R8U:~/c$ make
make: unname-r: Command not found
make -C/lib/modules//build M=/home/shantanu/cmodules
make[1]: *** /lib/modules//build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
Makefile:3: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: What are you trying to `make`? It seems the developer mistyped `uname -r`.

Comment: can create a temporary solution `bash -c 'unname-r(){ uname -r; }; make'`

Comment: @bac0n The shell function won't be inherited by `make`. A script, placed in a directory listed in `$PATH`, would work. But the best solution is probably to modify the makefile. It looks like this is the OP's own makefile so I don't expect any problems doing that.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the command should be `uname -r`, not `unname-r`.